# I am getting error in return count saying"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

```
public IActionResult DeluxRoomCount()
{
   string deluxRoom = "select COUNT(type) from Rooms where Type='Delxu' And Avilability='True'";
   int count = 0;
   using (SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HootelReservationDb1"))
        {
           using (SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand(deluxRoom, thisConnection))
                {
                    thisConnection.Open();
                    count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                return count;
        }
 }
```

i am hoping that there will be some ideas to count sql data and i am tring to understand what is wrong with this code

Comment: try (int)(decimal)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to cast into drive class which implement IActionResult. try this.

```
public IActionResult DeluxRoomCount()
{
   string deluxRoom = "select COUNT(type) from Rooms where Type='Delxu' And Avilability='True'";
   int count = 0;
   using (SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HootelReservationDb1"))
        {
           using (SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand(deluxRoom, thisConnection))
                {
                    thisConnection.Open();
                    count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
                }
        }

    return Ok(count)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Method's return type is IActionResult, But you're returning an int and in order to make your method work, You'll need to return an IActionResult.
Here is some reference on how to do that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: References come and go, links break. Your answer would be better (and meet the site's content guidelines) if you included an example that specifically addresses how to do it with the code in the question.